# State handlers depends on concrete Context in state pattern

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, state-pattern

I have a base context `BattleUnit` derived from `Unit` which has two state `Idle` and `Engaging`. And these two states will have a reference to the instance of `BattleUnit` in order to handle the state. From `BattleUnit` I derived a `Troop` which is movable thus having two additional states `Marching` and `Chasing`. So if my `State` is designed as:

```
public abstract class State {
    protected Unit unit;
    public abstract void Handle();
}
```

In `Idle` and `Engaging` state I want to handle a instance of `BattleUnit`. I can attack or just stay idle. But I need to manipulate the interface of `BattleUnit` which may not exit in `Unit`. And similarly I want to handle a instance of `Troop:BattleUnit` in `Marching` or `Chasing`.

So can I just cast the Unit to the class I expect? i.e:

```
public class Engaging : State {
    public void Handle() {
        Troop trp = (Troop)unit;
        // trp.troopMethod() which is not virtual
    }
}
```

PS: I have a instance of `State` in my`Unit` like:

```
public class Unit{
    private State state;
    //...
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you really need to have a reference to the Unit in the State-class? If the Handle-method is invoked from the Unit, it could pass itself as a parameter to the method.  

You would still need to cast the Unit to the correct type in the Handle-method. But this change might still make the design a little bit simpler.

Comment: Yeah, this is a workaround. I asked someone else who tell me this is basically a double dispatch problem. A modify of @YuvalItzchakov 's solution will work. That is keep the abstract class State, While template the concrete State.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could try is having you states work for a specific type of entity, for example states to manipulate a `BattleUnit` and states to manipulate a `Troop`. So, for example you would start off with a base state similar to:

```
public abstract class State<T> where T : Unit
{
    protected State(T unit)
    {
        this.Unit = unit;
    }

    protected T Unit { get; private set; }
    public abstract void Handle();
}
```

You would then create the `Engaging` and `Idle` states for you `BattleUnit`:

```
public class EngagingState : State<BattleUnit>
{
    public EngagingState(BattleUnit unit)
        : base(unit)
    {
    }

    public override void Handle()
    {
        //  Here you can implement the "engaging" logic for a BattleUnit.
        this.Unit.X = ????;
        this.Unit.Y = ????;        
    }
}
```

You would then do the same for the `Idle` state:

```
public class IdleState : State<BattleUnit>
{
    ...
}
```

These two states could be applied to any instance that derives from `BattleUnit` (assuming `BattleUnit` is not abstract!).

For you `Troop` class you would create two classes called `MarchingState` and `ChasingState` and the structure would be similar to the classes outlined above, but the base class would be `State<Troop>`. In the `Handle` method you would perform the "Marching" and "Chasing" logic for a `Troop` instance. Now if you later decided that you would like a "Chasing" state for a vehicle, then you could create the following:

```
public class VehicleChasingState : State<Vehicle>
{
    public VehicleChasingState(Vehicle unit)
        : base(unit)
    {
    }

    public override void Handle()
    {
        //  Here you can implement the "chasing" logic for a Vehicle.
        this.Unit.X = ????;
        this.Unit.Y = ????;

        if(this.Unit.HasRadar)
        {
            //  Do special "chasing" logic when the vehicle has radar.
        }
    }
}
```

This class would then accept a `Vehicle` instance in the constructor and the `Handle` method would perform the "Chasing" logic for a vehicle. One reason for having different states for different entities, even if the purpose of the state is similar, is to allow you to implement special logic within your state, e.g. in this case the "Chasing" logic for a `Vehicle` checks for the existence of radar, but in the "Chasing" state for a `Troop` you would not want to do this (in this example anyway :)).

EDIT 1:

@zoujyjs ... In answer to your comment there are really two ways to solve this:

The first would be to create a `IState` interface that will contain a `void Handle()` method and would be implemented by the base `State<T>` class. Your `Unit` class would then have a `protected IState CurrentState { get; set; }` property. Each of the derived classes, at some point, would assign a new state to this property:

```
this.CurrentState = new EngagingState(this); //  ...this is inside a BattleUnit instance

//  or

this.CurrentState = new MarchingState(this); //  ...this is inside a Troop instance
```

Then at some point the `Unit` class would simply call `this.CurrentState.Handle()`. The main point of having an `IState`, without generic parameters, is the `Unit` class doesn't need to know the type of instance being managed by the state. All it needs to know is it has to call the `Handle` method. The added benefit of having the generic parameter on the `State<T>` class is to make it easier to implement logic.

But, the generic parameter is not necessary which leads me onto the second option:

You could remove the generic parameter and the `Unit` property from the base `State` class and each derived state would still accept a concrete type, i.e. BattleUnit or Troop, but instead of passing it onto the base `State` class it would hold a reference as a member variable. Therefore your `Handle` methods would look somethig like:

```
public override void Handle()
{
    _unit.X = ????;
    _unit.Y = ????;
}
```

Your `Unit` class can then hold a reference to `State` and you can ignore the need for the `IState` interface mentioned above.

Comment: In this way I have to keep a reference to `State<Unit> state` in `Unit`, but another `State<Troop> state` in `Troop` which will hidden the Unit state inherited. But anyway if I get more complicated requirements, this is a good thought. I guess I will use cast as a workaround now. I've spent too much time here, better to meet my deadline first :).

Comment: @zoujyjs...I've updated my answer to take into account your comment. I understand you are going with the "cast" approach, but the answer may be useful to someone else. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about making State accept a generic parameter of type `Unit`?

```
public abstract class State<out T> where T : Unit
{
   protected T unit;
   public abstract void Handle();
}

public class Engaging : State<Troop> {
  public void Handle() {
    unit.troopMethod();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is gonna work. Because I also have a `State` instance in `BattleUnit` to indicate current state, and I have a rule to change state. This makes every state not derived from a common root, but a different one. Am I correct?

Comment: No. Unit is still the root of all, I did not change the inheritance hierarchy

Comment: I mean the state is no longer inthe same hierarchy now. I can't change state in unit.

Comment: Why is there a circular dependency between `State` and `Unit`?

Comment: But it need to. Apparently, `Unit` need to maintain a current `State` and call `State.Handle()` to do something according to that `State`. And when `State` is handling issues, it needs to do something to Unit, e.g. `Troop.Move()` and `BattleUnit` can NOT `Move`.